# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "xxxx/libnative-lib.so" has bad ELF magic

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

On a new rom, when I first time to install a app,it crashed after I open it. The error log is as follows:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/com.xxx.xxxxxx-CWtD7wT_6qo9DhcXze8XaQ==/lib/arm64/libnative-lib.so"
>   has bad ELF magic.

Then I deleted the app and restart the phone, install the same app again,it opens normally.

Comment: Probably just a corrupt or truncated file.   The ELF magic is the first 4 bytes of the file; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format#File_header

Comment: Thanks for your answer